# C++ virtual destructor inlining for stack allocated objects

Tags: c++, inline

Is a compiler allowed to inline a virtual destructor in the case of the implicit destruction of stack allocated objects?

I understand the 'delete' operation must call the virtual destructor via the virtual function table (e.g. it can't inline), since it can't know the exact class the pointer refers to.

But when an object is allocated on the stack, the compiler knows the exact class. So I would've thought it would be free to inline the implicit destruction since it can see the actual destructors for the class. If the compiler is not allowed to do that, then why not? What scenario can override the destructor to something different than the compiler knows it to be?

Comment: Is the an actual problem you could demonstrate with code, or is your question about why certain optimizations are not done?

Comment: The compiler may optimize any virtual function (inline, elide, ...) whenever possible.

Comment: Look at *devirtualization*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, compilers can inline virtual destructor in this case. Let's consider an code example:

```
#include <iostream>

int global = 0;

class A {
public:
  virtual void foo() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
  virtual ~A() { ++global; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
  virtual void foo() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
  virtual ~B() { --global; }
};

int main() {
  {
    B b[5];
    b[0].foo();
  }
  std::cout << "global: " << global << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/PWEVW8

As you can see clang 3.8 with -O3 optimization will not ever generate code for classes (gcc 6.1 with -O3 will generate class B, but will inline destructor anyway):

```
main:                                   # @main
        pushq   %r14
        pushq   %rbx
        pushq   %rax
        movl    std::cout, %edi
        movl    $.L.str.2, %esi
        movl    $1, %edx
        callq   std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        movq    std::cout(%rip), %rax
        movq    -24(%rax), %rax
        movq    std::cout+240(%rax), %rbx
        testq   %rbx, %rbx
        je      .LBB0_9
        cmpb    $0, 56(%rbx)
        je      .LBB0_3
        movb    67(%rbx), %al
        jmp     .LBB0_4
.LBB0_3:
        movq    %rbx, %rdi
        callq   std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const
        movq    (%rbx), %rax
        movl    $10, %esi
        movq    %rbx, %rdi
        callq   *48(%rax)
.LBB0_4:                                # %_ZNKSt5ctypeIcE5widenEc.exit2
        movsbl  %al, %esi
        movl    std::cout, %edi
        callq   std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::put(char)
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        callq   std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::flush()
        movl    std::cout, %edi
        movl    $.L.str, %esi
        movl    $8, %edx
        callq   std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        movl    global(%rip), %esi
        movl    std::cout, %edi
        callq   std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        movq    %rax, %r14
        movq    (%r14), %rax
        movq    -24(%rax), %rax
        movq    240(%r14,%rax), %rbx
        testq   %rbx, %rbx
        je      .LBB0_9
        cmpb    $0, 56(%rbx)
        je      .LBB0_7
        movb    67(%rbx), %al
        jmp     .LBB0_8
.LBB0_7:
        movq    %rbx, %rdi
        callq   std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const
        movq    (%rbx), %rax
        movl    $10, %esi
        movq    %rbx, %rdi
        callq   *48(%rax)
.LBB0_8:                                # %std::ctype<char>::widen(char) const [clone .exit]
        movsbl  %al, %esi
        movq    %r14, %rdi
        callq   std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::put(char)
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        callq   std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::flush()
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        addq    $8, %rsp
        popq    %rbx
        popq    %r14
        retq
.LBB0_9:
        callq   std::__throw_bad_cast()

        pushq   %rax
        movl    std::__ioinit, %edi
        callq   std::ios_base::Init::Init()
        movl    std::ios_base::Init::~Init(), %edi
        movl    std::__ioinit, %esi
        movl    $__dso_handle, %edx
        popq    %rax
        jmp     __cxa_atexit            # TAILCALL

global:
        .long   0                       # 0x0

.L.str:
        .asciz  "global: "

.L.str.2:
        .asciz  "B"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is a compiler allowed to inline a virtual destructor in the case of the implicit destruction of stack allocated objects?

Yes. As long as it calls the destructor of the correct runtime type of the object.

> I understand the 'delete' operation must call the virtual destructor via the virtual function table (e.g. it can't inline), since it can't know the exact class the pointer refers to.

*Only if* the compiler can't know what concrete type the pointer refers to, must it make a virtual call.

> But when an object is allocated on the stack, the compiler knows the exact class.

Correct.

> So I would've thought it would be free to inline the implicit destruction since it can see the actual destructors for the class.

Well, being allocated on the stack does not guarantee that the definition of the destructor is visible. But if it is visible, then your assumption is correct, the compiler is free to inline.